# How can I do my regional language application applicable for OS 6 OS 7

Tags: blackberry

I had done my regional language(telugu) application .it is working in OS 7 (9790) but I need it in OS 6 also all the mechanism is working like parsing ,but not displaying the font(appears like boxes).

plz help me to over come this situation

Answer (score 0):

With the OS6 device, try loading a web page with telugu, to make sure the device is configured properly with fonts.  If the web browser is not able to render the telugu text, then you need to look into the device's font configuration.